# Mysql self join and without deplicate

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have following table:

```
Name
a
b
c
d
```

And I want to get below results.

```
╔════════╦════════════╗
║ Name1  ║ Name2      ║
╠════════╬════════════╣
║      a ║          b ║
║      a ║          c ║
║      a ║          d ║
║      b ║          c ║
║      b ║          d ║
║      c ║          d ║
╚════════╩════════════╝
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

That's a self join with an inequality condition:

```
select a.name name1, b.name name2
from mytable a
inner join mytable b on b.name > a.name
```